# Axis2 WSDL2Java : missing no-arg operation in generated stub

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I've got in my webservice a simple `public boolean isAlive()` service.
I defined it in my WSDL :

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:element name="isAliveResponse" type="xsd:boolean">
    </xsd:element>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="isAliveResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="ns:isAliveResponse" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="myService">
    <wsdl:operation name="isAlive">
        <wsdl:output message="ns:isAliveResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="myServiceSOAP" type="ns:myService">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="isAlive">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://myServiceURL/isAlive" />
    <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
    </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
```

When I generate the Service skeleton the method is generated but not in the client stub. Is there a problem in the WSDL ? Should I put a wsdl:input even if the method don't have arguments (I didn't put the whole WSDL but all the other method with a "request" arg are well generated) ? And if I have to put a wsdl:input what would be it's message ?

**Edit** : After validating the WSDL under Eclipse I have the warning  `WS-I: (BP2208) wsdl:operation was not a request/response or one-way operation` after searching I found a description here : http://www.ws-i.org/Testing/Tools/2005/01/BP11_TAD_1-1.htm#BP2208 (it seems the anchor doesn't work) so I guess the error is probably the missing wsdl:input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in my edit the problem was the missing wsdl:input. By adding

```
<wsdl:input message="ns:isAliveRequest" />
```

and

```
<wsdl:message name="isAliveRequest"></wsdl:message>
```

then my original problem is solved... conclusion, I should have searched more by myself before to ask on SO :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your problem but the following line seems to have no closing tag:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:element name="isAliveResponse" type="xsd:boolean">
</wsdl:types>
```

It should be like this:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:element name="isAliveResponse" type="xsd:boolean"/>
</wsdl:types>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it was just an error in my copy/paste but the original was correct... I edited the question to correct that.